# Access database advice

Tags: database, microsoft-access, query

I'm new to access so this might sound stupid.

I have few thousands csv files, each one containing few hundred rows of transactions data for an item. Each csv file is a different item.

I want to use MS Access to create a database with all the transactions.

Should I use a single big table with all the transactions in it, or I should add each csv file (item) as a different table?

In the end, the database will be used to show all transactions for an item in a userform datasheet, show statistics using simple queries and vba and show some charts with this statistics.

I estimate several million rows of data in total. So I need it to run fast considering the amount of data.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd steer away from MS Access completely. The maximum record set size in a query is 1GB, something that you'll easily exceed if you run stats over all your records. Also, the single table limit in Access is 2GB, which is also very easily reached with millions of records. That's not even speaking of the very likely performance issues you'll run into. Look into a real RDBMS solution; MySQL or Postgres or something. MS Access was just not designed for these kind of data sets. ODBC bindings for MySQL and Postgres exist, so you likely can still use the same frontend.

Comment: Thanks for your support. Unfortunately I'm limited to MS Office only. I'll try to get rid of all redundant data so I'll have a smaller dataset. Could you still advise on table type choosing? The statistics will only be calculated for each particular item, max 500 rows of data in a query.

Comment: If you're planning to limit the "calculation" with a WHERE clause, you're still querying the entire table, so I'd say, draw your own conclusions...